# Can a "depressive soliton" wave exist? That is, can we have a trough without any crest? Why or why not?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, differential-equations, solitons

I know that "soliton" waves can consist of a crest without a trough. One would expect the reverse to be true as well.

However, [this Wikipedia excerpt says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)#Shallow_water),

> So for this nonlinear gravity wave it is the total water depth under the wave crest that determines the speed, with higher waves traveling faster than lower waves. Note that solitary wave solutions only exist for positive values of H, solitary gravity waves of depression do not exist.

Is this true, and if so, why?

Comment: Can you give a citation to the specific language in that page? Did they say that equations that produce solitons can not have an almost everywhere nearly constant non-zero solution with a stable "dip" in them?

Comment: A link to the Wikipedia article Dispersion (water waves) in section [shallow water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(water_waves)#Shallow_water).

Comment: This is a good question and its answer is nontrivial.

Comment: From the very deep past what I can recall is that the issue is *related* to the fact the higher the wave the faster it is, thus a depression cannot be stable. This you can see by neglecting the dispersive term represented by the 3rd derivative $u_{xxx}$ and by writing the remainder of the KdV as $u_t+uu_x$ whose solution is $u=f(s)$ with $s=x-ut$ for *any* differentiable $f(s)$. This shows that the apparent *nondispersive* wave speed *is* $u$. In a trough the surrounding is always at a higher speed than the trough itself, so it cannot be stable.